# How to make skeletons for the element ui table

Tags: vuejs3, element-ui

I have a table that outputs 10 rows of company data. I would like 10 rows with skeletons in rows to be displayed when loading data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI4Bs.png)I would like to take the skeletons from the same library. Please tell me what to do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to add a little bit of code here, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example